# UNION in MYSQL and merge columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am fetching data from two tables in mysql. I have query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(debit IS NULL, 0, debit)) - SUM(IF(credit IS NULL, 0, credit)) as amount, th.country_id, cl.currency_name
FROM account_treasury_hq th
LEFT JOIN system_country_list cl ON cl.country_id=th.country_id
WHERE th.company_id='$company_id'
GROUP BY th.country_id

UNION

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ce_type = 'IN' or ce_type is NULL then payment_amount
                WHEN ce_type = 'OUT' then - payment_amount
                END) as amount,
source_country_id as country_id, cl.currency_name
FROM customer_payment_options cpo
LEFT JOIN system_country_list cl ON cl.country_id=cpo.source_country_id
WHERE cpo.company_id='$company_id'
GROUP BY cpo.source_country_id
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [amount] => -345
        [country_id] => 40
        [currency_name] => Canadian dollar
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 93
        [country_id] => 210
        [currency_name] => Sri Lankan rupee
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 46.5
        [country_id] => 236
        [currency_name] => United States dollar
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 916249.8999999999
        [country_id] => 40
        [currency_name] => Canadian dollar
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [amount] => -6670.1
        [country_id] => 210
        [currency_name] => Sri Lankan rupee
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 2017.67
        [country_id] => 236
        [currency_name] => United States dollar
    )

)
```

In the result array, you can see the same country_id. I want to merge those same country id with 1. It means, there should only be each amount information for each country_id.
(`amount` should be added by adding multiple countries)
Is there any way to do it in `PHP` or `mysql` itself?
Thanks for any kind of help.

**Required Result**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 915904.89
        [country_id] => 40
        [currency_name] => Canadian dollar
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [amount] => -6577.1
        [country_id] => 210
        [currency_name] => Sri Lankan rupee
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 2064.17
        [country_id] => 236
        [currency_name] => United States dollar
    )
)
```

Comment: Why are you using UNION? why not just join the other query together on identical id's

Comment: Wrap the entire thing in a `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...)...` and do a `GROUP BY` on the other part.

Comment: Actually. these two tables are not related with each other. I want to take information from both tables and merge it in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just select it all in an outer query sum the amount and group by country_id

```
SELECT 
    SUM(amount) country_id, currency_name
FROM 
(   SELECT 
        SUM(IF(debit IS NULL, 0, debit)) - SUM(IF(credit IS NULL, 0, credit)) as amount,
        th.country_id, 
        cl.currency_name
    FROM account_treasury_hq th
    LEFT JOIN system_country_list cl ON cl.country_id=th.country_id
    WHERE th.company_id='$company_id'
    GROUP BY th.country_id

    UNION

    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE 
               WHEN ce_type = 'IN' or ce_type is NULL then payment_amount
               WHEN ce_type = 'OUT' then - payment_amount
               END
        ) as amount,
        source_country_id as country_id, 
        cl.currency_name
    FROM customer_payment_options cpo
    LEFT JOIN system_country_list cl ON cl.country_id=cpo.source_country_id
    WHERE cpo.company_id='$company_id'
    GROUP BY cpo.source_country_id
) t
GROUP BY country_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a `union`, with grouping in the individual subquery. Each subquery in a union has NO awareness of what the other parallel queries are doing. Each query's `group by` will apply only to that ONE query.

You'd need to do the heavy duty work in a wrapper query, e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(.....)
FROM (
     SELECT th.country_id AS country_id, etc...
     UNION ALL
     SELECT source_country AS country_id, etc...
) AS foo
GROUP BY country_id
```

e.g. do all the grouping and "math" in the outer query, and the inner queries simply retrieve all the records you do want grouped together.

Answer (score -1):

Didn't test this (would need a sqlfiddle to play with) but you'd want to aggregate them in the query.  Something like this (you'll want to tweak the group by and select for your needs):

```
SELECT SUM( x.amount ), x.country_id, x.currency_name
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(IF(debit IS NULL, 0, debit)) - SUM(IF(credit IS NULL, 0, credit)) as     amount, th.country_id, cl.currency_name
    FROM account_treasury_hq th
    LEFT JOIN system_country_list cl ON cl.country_id=th.country_id
    WHERE th.company_id='$company_id'
    GROUP BY th.country_id

    UNION

   SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ce_type = 'IN' or ce_type is NULL then payment_amount
            WHEN ce_type = 'OUT' then - payment_amount
            END) as amount,
source_country_id as country_id, cl.currency_name
   FROM customer_payment_options cpo
   LEFT JOIN system_country_list cl ON cl.country_id=cpo.source_country_id
   WHERE cpo.company_id='$company_id'
   GROUP BY cpo.source_country_id
) AS x
GROUP BY x.amount, x.country_id, x.currency_name
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `x.amount` should not be present in `GROUP BY`.